# Django Class based view filtering queryset but not?

Tags: python, django

I have a bit of a challenge with the way a date filter is working:

Django Class based view, starting here https://github.com/varlenthegray/wcadmin/blob/master/customer/views.py#L61

```py
class CustomersCustomReport(generic.ListView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'customer/reports/custom_report.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        from_date = self.request.GET.get('fromDate')
        to_date = self.request.GET.get('toDate')
        self.queryset = Customer.objects.filter(is_active=True)

        if from_date:
            from_date = datetime.strptime(from_date, '%m-%d-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            print("Checking date from " + from_date)

            self.queryset.filter(next_service__gte=from_date)

        if to_date:
            to_date = datetime.strptime(to_date, '%m-%d-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            print("Checking date to " + to_date)
            self.queryset.filter(next_service__lte=to_date)

        return self.queryset
```

I'm expecting this to return a filtered query based on the date that is a form field.

https://wcadmin.innovated.tech/customer/report/custom_report?fromDate=04-01-2022&toDate=04-30-2022

I know this data isn't filtered because the entire customer list is 521 entries of mock data that are active. I was following information from this question: [How Can I Filter By Date Range Using Djangos Built in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70552398/how-can-i-filter-by-date-range-using-djangos-built-in-listview)

I know it's getting data from the database, I know it's getting the date range I want from the URL due to the print, and the model is set to DateField for next_service, so I'm not quite sure what's going wrong here?

Comment: The lines `self.queryset.filter(next_service__gte=from_date)` return a new queryset. At the end of the method it returns the original `self.queryset`. A change such as `self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(next_service__gte=from_date)` will fix this

Comment: AH interesting, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need only a little changes:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    from_date = self.request.GET.get('fromDate')
    to_date = self.request.GET.get('toDate')
    queryset = Customer.objects.filter(is_active=True) # change

    if from_date:
        from_date = datetime.strptime(from_date, '%m-%d-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print("Checking date from " + from_date)

        queryset = queryset.filter(next_service__gte=from_date) # change

    if to_date:
        to_date = datetime.strptime(to_date, '%m-%d-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print("Checking date to " + to_date)
        queryset = queryset.filter(next_service__lte=to_date) # change

    return queryset # change
```